# Unserialize two arrays

Tags: php, serialization

I have serialized two arrays.

```
a:2:{s:4:"name";s:3:"foo";s:8:"passwort";s:3:"bar";}a:2:{s:4:"name";s:3:"bar";s:8:"passwort";s:3:"foo";}
```

Now I want to unserialize them. (They´re saved in $file)

```
$db=unserialize( file_get_contents($file) );
print_r($db);
```

Output:

```
Array ( [name] => foo [passwort] => bar )
```

So only the first one was printed... how can bundle both in one array?

Thanks in advance

M00LTi

Answer (score 1):

You've borked the serialize-format when you've appended a serialized array to an already serialized one. The serialized variable should only map to one single variable. If you want to serialize two arrays as one structure, serialize an array containing both:

```
serialize(array($arr1, $arr2))
```

You can then unserialize both: `list($arr1, $arr2) = unserialize($data)`, or by doing `$arrays = unserialize($data)` and then accessing `$arrays[0]` and `$arrays[1]`.

If you want to repair your defunct format, you'll have to extract the two parts by themselves and call `unserialize()` on each part. If you know your data well, you can probably do it manually this time, or you implement a small parser for the serialized format to discover when the previous entry ends and you can start serializing a new entry (by scanning for }a outside of a string).